# How do you turn this into a variable?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out how would I turn this into a variable so that I can call it multiple times?

```
.appendTo(".main").hide().delay(250).fadeIn(500);

$(browserMessage + "Internet Explorer not Supported" + browserMessage2 + "Your version of Internet Explorer is not supported - Please Upgrade to 9 or Higher to Continue" + browserMessage3).appendTo(".main").hide().delay(250).fadeIn(500); }
```

Comment: You want to turn it into a function, not a variable. That should help your searching.

Comment: do u want to get all above codes output into a variable ?

Comment: @Kevin Not necessarily. The OP may well use a String variable to store the computed String if it is one-off.

Comment: I'm looking to add the append line to a function so that I can call it multiple times without having to write it out everytime.

Comment: Is your IE string, and your `browserMessage` variables, going to change, or always stay the same?

Comment: They will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function () {
    $(browserMessage + "Internet Explorer not Supported" + browserMessage2 + "Your version of Internet Explorer is not supported - Please Upgrade to 9 or Higher to Continue" + browserMessage3).appendTo(".main").hide().delay(250).fadeIn(500);
}
```

and call this function anywhere, like on button click:

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    $.fn.myFunction();
});
```

P.S. Assuming the variables browserMessage, browserMessage2 and browserMessage3 are global.

Answer (score 2):

You can try turning this into a function:

```
function appendMessage(el) {
    el.appendTo(".main").hide().delay(250).fadeIn(500);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
appendMessage($(".yourMessageElement"));
```

Comment: And according to the question, probably `".main"`.